# Chrome extension with python

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension where I need to take the text of the current webpage and save that text in the input file on hard disk. This file I need to use in the python program which i'l be running in the back end. This python script will create a output file after processing the input file. Then i'll display this file content on the same webpage in the form of pop up. Now I am need to know how will I create the file,write into it and read from it in chrome. Is there any way to do this???

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Chrome Extensions are merely glorified javascript snippets.  With the limitations of javascript and chrome's sandboxing I doubt you can do File I/O let alone talking to a native application.  I'd say the best you can do use Chrome's [LocalStorage](http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm) or [WebDatabase](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) APIs.  You'll have to poke around to see where these things are actually stored (hacky hacky).